# How Do I Access The Intersection Of A DataSet Using A Table?

Tags: r

I am a beginner at R.

I have a table, t, and I want to get the P(gender|vote). So, I tried it the way it intuitively would be done, print(t[gender][vote]). I am doing this because I am trying to get the P(Yes|Female). If you could help this beginner out that would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

```
x = read.csv2("./chilean_voting.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep=",");

x[,5] = floor(x[,5]/10)

vote = 9;                           
education = 6;
gender = 4;
region = 1
age = 5;
region = 2;


t = table(x[,c(education,gender,age,region,vote)])

print(x[age])
print(t[age][gender])
```

https://repl.it/repls/EcstaticLowPaintprogram

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Probably the best thing to do is edit your question to include a snippet of your data and the desired output based on that snippet.

Comment: In general, avoid naming variables the same as `R` functions. Your table `t` can be confused with `R`'s transpose function `t`.